# Simple way to re-assign values in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble reassigning values in an array.

```
    public static void main(String[] {

            int[] arrayOfIntegers = new int[4];
            arrayOfIntegers[0] = 11;
            arrayOfIntegers[1] = 12;
            arrayOfIntegers[2] = 13;
            arrayOfIntegers[3] = 14;

            arrayOfIntegers = {11,12,15,17};

    }
```

Why am I unable to reassign values in the manner that I've attempted? If I can't do it, why can't I do it?

Comment: A little off-topic: You should name the variable `arrayOfIntegers` (starting uncapitalized). See also http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why am I unable to reassign values in the manner that I've attempted? If I can't do it, why can't I do it?

Because Java doesn't have *destructuring assignment* like some other languages do.

Your choices are:

1. Assign a *new* array to the array variable as shown by Rohit and Kayaman, but that's not what you asked. You said you wanted to assign to the elements. If you assign a new array to `ArrayOfIntegers`, anything else that has a reference to the old array in a different variable or member will still refer to the old array.
2. Use [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29), but it involves creating a temporary array:

   ```
    System.arraycopy(new int[]{11,12,15,17},
                     0,
                     ArrayOfIntegers,
                     0,
                     ArrayOfIntegers.length);
   ```

`System.arraycopy` will copy the elements into the existing array.

Comment: I had some quick questions and want to make sure I get this right. In Part 1 of your reply, when you say "anything else that has a reference to the old array", are you talking about subclasses that would reference `ArrayOfIntegers`? In regards to how System.arraycopy works, `ArrayOfIntegers` begins as `[11,12,13,14]`. Then a temporary array is created using System.arraycopy which replaces elements in the original 'ArrayOfIntegers'? How is this different from deconstructing assignment?

Comment: Also, what are "deconstructing assignments"? I thought assignments were simply changing the value of a variable and that the only "special" type of assignment as initialization since it's the first assignment.

Comment: @TomFang: A "deconstructing assignment" is where you have some kind of compound variable on the left-hand side and a compound value on the right-hand side, and each value on the right-hand side is assigned to the corresponding portion left-hand side variable. For instance, in languages that support them, you could literally have `int a; int b; (a, b) = (1, 2);` resulting in `a` being `1`, and `b` being `2`. The thing on the right is "deconstructed" into individual parts, and then assigned to the individual parts identified on the left. This is useful when the right-hand side is a return value.

Comment: @TomFang: *"`ArrayOfIntegers` begins as [11,12,13,14]. Then a temporary array is created using System.arraycopy which replaces elements in the original 'ArrayOfIntegers'?"* The temporary array isn't created by `arraycopy`, it's created by the array initializer we pass into `arraycopy`. *"How is this different from deconstructing assignment?"* It's very similar, which is why I pointed it out, because `arraycopy` takes each element of the source array and assigns it to the corresponding element of the destination array.

Comment: @TomFang: *"...when you say "anything else that has a reference to the old array", are you talking about subclasses that would reference ArrayOfIntegers?"* Not necessarily. It could be as simple as `int[] a = ArrayOfIntegers; ArrayOfIntegers = new int[] { 11, 12, 15, 17};` Now, `a` refers to the **old** array, and `ArrayOfIntegers` refers to a new, completely separate, array. Whereas with `arraycopy`, they both continue to refer to the same array.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - No (well, not as far as I know), it was a typo. :-) Fixed, thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide the type of array. Use this:

```
arrayOfIntegers = new int[] {11,12,15,17};
```

From [JLS Section 10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> An array initializer may be specified in a declaration (§8.3, §9.3, §14.4), or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10), to create an array and provide some initial values.

If you are trying to re-assign array elements in some range, you can't do that with direct assignment. Either you need to assign values at indices individually, or use the way as given by @TJCrowder in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is:

```
arrayOfIntegers = new int[]{11,12,15,17};
```